# joomla 3 extensions migration to joomla 4

Tags: extensions, migration, joomla-4

I developed several extensions on Joomla 3 and I want to migrate my extensions (components, modules, plugins) to Joomla 4. I searched on the net and I didn't find any information about upgrading J3 component to J4.

I want to know if I have to adapt my extensions and if I do, what are the fix I need to apply

Comment: This is a good place to start https://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_4.

Answer (score 2):

I've been adapting my custom J3 modules into J4 locally in a WAMP environment followed by installing them on a live test site. So far the only change I've had to make is adding the <namespace> to the module .xml files. These are simple extensions which display frontend content. Your mileage may vary depending on how complicated your modules are.

Here are a couple overviews I found while I was prepping my modules

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jUc5sMqb22E

https://joomla.digital-peak.com/images/blog/JWC17_Prepare_you_extension_for_Joomla_4.pdf

For J4 Modules you may want to look at these resources

https://docs.joomla.org/Special:MyLanguage/J4.x:Creating_a_Simple_Module

https://github.com/ceford/j4xdemos-mod-mydownmsg

I also downloaded J4-compatible modules from the [JED](https://extensions.joomla.org/) and looked through their files to see how they were written

I haven't tried building a component yet but I found these resources

https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component

https://docs.joomla.org/J4_Component_example_-_Mywalks

https://blog.astrid-guenther.de/en/der-weg-zu-joomla4-erweiterungen/
https://github.com/ceford/j4xdemos-com-mywalks

Again, downloading and examining some J4-compatible components might provide useful guidance and insight.